# Deadlock - due to long transaction SQL server

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, deadlock

I've got a stored procedure that runs 3 inner procedures
all within a one BEGIN TRANSACTION.

The environment is : Azure database sql

as a result i have many deadlocks for the table : TranStatus.
the lock that i get is : lockMode="RangeI-N"

question :

1. how can i deal with lockMode RangeI-N?
2. any other suggestion for improving the performance i've overlooked?

what i've done so far :

1. shorten the transaction
2. removed the foreign key constraint from trns table to trnsStatus table
3. used Insert into where not exists logic.
4. Scaled up to azure database

here is my of my stored procedure code that starts with BEGIN TRANSACITON:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;      
    INSERT INTO FCUG.Trs ([TrLnk], [Lbl], [CrId], [CrBalId], [CusTrsType], [TrsLocTime], [TrsfId], [CorrId], [Crted],
    [RefNum], [TrsCat], SrcBkAccId, PymntSchmId,
    PymntRef, DestBkAccId, OutPymntId, CrdInstncId, DrctDbtDueID, TrsCntryIso,McCd
    )
    VALUES
    (@TrLnk, @Lbl, @CrId, @CrBalId, @CusTrsType, @TrsLocTime, @TrsfId, @CorrId, @Crted, @RefNum, @TrsCat, @SrcBkAccId, @PymntSchmId,
    @PymntRef, @DestBkAccId, @OutPymntId, @CrdInstncId, @DrctDbtDueID, @TrsCntryIso,@McCd
    )

    SET @TrsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    EXEC @TrsStatusId = [Trs].[AddTrsStatus]
        @TrsId,
        @TrsStatusType,
        @AuthType,
        @HldAmt,
        @HldCurr,
        @TrsAmt,
        @TrsCurr,
        @AccumAmt,
        @CorrId,
        @Crted, 
        @EventTs,
        @BaseConvRate,
        @HldConvRate,
        @CrcyConvFee,
        @AccumTrsAmt,
        @TrsCrcyConvRate,
        @MaintId,
        @FailRsnId,
        @RiskRlCds,
        @MkTrsAsSuspRiskAct,
        @ChngCrdStatusToRiskRiskAct,
        @ChngAccStatusToSuspRiskAct,
        @RejTrsRiskAct


    IF (@PrvId IS NOT NULL AND @PrvTrsId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC [Trs].[AddTrsPrvContract] @TrsId, @PrvId, @PrvTrsId, @CorrId, @Crted
    END


    IF (@ShldAffctAvailBal = 1)
        BEGIN
            EXEC [Trs].[AddAvailBal]
                    @CrBalId,
                    @AccumAmt,
                    @CorrId,
                    @Crted,
                    @TrsId 
            
        END

    IF (@ShldAffctSettldBal = 1)
        BEGIN
            EXEC [Trs].[AddSettledBal]
                        @CrBalId,
                        @AccumAmt,
                        @CorrId,
                        @Crted 
                
        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

i've got a deadlock in the [Trs].[AddTrsStatus]
specificly in INSERT INTO Cug.TrnStatus.

I've traced the deadlock
and here is the result:

```
  <process id="process1f44312c8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="1212" waitresource="KEY: 17:72057594051166208 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="1821" ownerId="120045" transactionname="transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-03-14T15:45:21.903" XDES="0x1f433e08460" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="3" kpid="60316" status="suspended" spid="110" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2024-03-14T15:45:22.003" lastbatchcompleted="2024-03-14T15:45:21.903" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.903" clientapp="Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="trns-service-7fbbbb756-7rt4l" hostpid="1" loginname="SomeUser" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="120045" currentdb="17" currentdbname="CustDB" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="410c905e-c091-47bd-8106-55c659e607de.Trns.AddTrnStatus" queryhash="0xf53075755900ee61" queryplanhash="0xd281ff8363347cf3" line="29" stmtstart="2170" stmtend="5738" sqlhandle="0x030011006a059379cf2fd1000eb1000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
INSERT INTO CUG.TrnStatuses ( 
*** some data   ***
   </frame>
```

the execution plan for insert trnsStatus is:
[image]

Comment: Please add the exact T-SQL definition of your tables and indexes on those tables.  Please ensure you [edit] the details into your question, instead of adding them as comments.  Take a quick look at [mcve] for a good example of how to format your question.  For the execution plan, it might be helpful to add the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add a link to it in your question.  It would also be helpful if you could add in the full deadlock xml via a [github gist](https://gist.github.com), with a link in your question.

Comment: Your deadlock graph is cut and all the useful information is not visible